# C++ static initialization of pointers/references between translation units

Tags: variables, static, initialization

First off, I have scoured stack overflow and the rest of the web and I am well aware of the following:
1) Global variables are Bad
2) Global variables dependencies between translation units is bad

However, we are using some middleware that is doing the following; and I can not ascertain whether this is dangerous.

```
// Global_Variable.hpp
#include "Type.hpp" /* this defines the type as a structure, doesn't really matter :) */
extern Type Global_Variable;   

// Global_Variable.cpp
#include "Global_Variable.hpp"
Type Global_Variable = { /* init the struct */ };

// Global_Reference.hpp
#include "Type.hpp"
extern Type & Global_Reference;

// Global_Reference.cpp
#include "Global_Reference.hpp"
#include "Global_Variable.hpp"
Type & Global_Reference = Global_Variable; // does this suffer from the SIOF?

// Global_Pointer.hpp
#include "Type.hpp"
extern Type * Global_Pointer

// Global_Reference.cpp
#include "Global_Pointer.hpp"
#include "Global_Variable.hpp"
Type * Global_Variable = &Global_Variable; // does this suffer from the SIOF?
```

I am worried that Global_Variable and Global_Reference could be initialized to null rather than Global_Variable, can this be the case?

Thanks!

Comment: I would argue that global variables are only "bad" in the way a knife is "bad". They have specific valid uses, but can be dangerous/problematic when used incorrectly. Most of the time they are not the best solution to a problem, even though they may be the "easiest" in some sense. Oh, and you don't want to leave toddlers unattended around them...

Comment: That's fair, but that's not pertinent to my question :(